# Data loading on MongoDB server works from jupyter notebook but not from script

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset stored in a json file and I need to upload it to a MongoDB server. Everything works fine if I upload the data using a Jupyter notebook, but not if I use a python script instead. The code is exactly the same. How do you suggest fixing this?

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
import DNS

# Function to upload the dialogue lines to MongoDB Server
def prepare_dataframe():
    dialogue_edited = pd.read_json("5lines1response_random100from880_cleaned.json")
    dialogue_edited.reset_index(inplace=True)
    data_dict = dialogue_edited.to_dict("records")# Insert collection
    # To communicate with the MongoDB Server
    cluster = MongoClient()
    db = cluster['DebuggingSystem']
    collection = db['MCS_dialogue']
    collection.insert_many(data_dict)
    return collection

if __name__ == '__main__':
    collection = prepare_dataframe()
```

Here is a screenshot of the python script and of the jupyter notebook. I'm running the notebook using Visual Studio.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    collection = prepare_dataframe()
```

with

```py
collection = prepare_dataframe()
```

and try runnning your script. `__main__` explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/9350720) pretty well.